# How to make two divs animate together?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently, I'm trying to make two divs animate together and in the same direction, but I'm on wrong way.
Here is my demo: https://jsbin.com/rebozamoca/edit?html,css,output
I specially need help !

Comment: If you include a resource from outside of SO, then include tbe relevant parts in your answer too.

Comment: Can you explain what is your desired output? And please add jQuery to your jsbin link.

Comment: I'm trying to animate those two divs at the same time and in the same direction. Also, now i will include jQuery

Comment: This is my new demo with jQuery library included, but I still have a problem with the animation: https://jsbin.com/lamenutacu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it.

Comment: Hey Peter try to solve this with transformation (translateX in your case) this is the better practice for moving elements